# NavMesh agent oscillating before going yo destination

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I have a NavMesh issue that's been bothering me for days.
When in "Patroling" state, the agents choose a random tile on the level and their destination is updated accordingly. Problem is, as you can see in the video, agents sometimes "oscilate" for a few seconds before their start going towards the destination - just like as if they were hesitating on which is the best path to choose.

See video : https://streamable.com/8quce

All tiles are accessible from anywhere on the level, and I verified that the destination is not being updated during the oscillation. Also, adjusting the agent's radius seems to reduce the oscillation but not to suppress it completely. The problem seems to occure more when there are several agents on the level. The pathStatus is always complete.

Comment: It looks like it could be the avoidance of others agents. Check these parameters in your NavMeshagents (you can set priority etc)